# How can i extract a specific sequence from serial data

Tags: python-3.x, pyserial

I am trying to read some serial data from raspberry pi 3 using pyserial api, I need the data in a particular sequence e.g 3xxx7xxxBxxxExxx, however, sometimes the data stream starts from Exxx3xxx7xxxBxxx, how can I ensure that I always read the right sequence irrespective of how the data streams in.

This is for reading data from a control card used in a special pump application.

```py
import serial
import time

ser = serial.Serial(
    port = '/dev/ttyACM0',
    baudrate = 9600,
    parity = serial.PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits = seial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS,
    timeout = 1
)

time.sleep = 1

try:
    while 1:
        if ser.inWaiting() > 0:
            data = ser.read(8)
            print(data.hex())
```

this gives me the result in 3xxx7xxxBxxxExxx sometimes and other times it starts from 7xxx or Exxx, however, I always want to be able to extract the sequence 3xxx7xxxBxxxExxx irrespective of where the stream starts from.

Comment: Maybe bit masking is the way to go but I am not familiar with it. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the marker which you use to determine the start of the sequence is a full byte `0x30` you can try the following code. It will read one byte at a time until the start marker is found. Then it will read another 7 bytes and append them:

```
import serial
import time

ser = serial.Serial(
    port = '/dev/ttyACM0',
    baudrate = 9600,
    parity = serial.PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits = seial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS,
    timeout = 1
)

time.sleep = 1

start_marker = b'\xE0'

try:
    while 1:
        if ser.inWaiting() > 0:
            data = ser.read(1)
            if data != start_marker:
                continue
            data += ser.read(7)
            print(data.hex())
```

## EDIT

Try this code to match the most significant 4 bits of each bytes pair:

```
import serial
import time

ser = serial.Serial(
    port = '/dev/ttyACM0',
    baudrate = 9600,
    parity = serial.PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits = seial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS,
    timeout = 1
)

time.sleep = 1
data = bytes()

try:
    while 1:
        if ser.inWaiting() > 0:
            data += ser.read(1)
            if len(data) < 8:
                continue
            if len(data) > 8:
                data = data[-8:]
            if not (
                data[0] >> 4 == 0x3 and
                data[2] >> 4 == 0x7 and
                data[4] >> 4 == 0xB and
                data[6] >> 4 == 0xE
            ):
                continue
            print(data.hex())
```

Comment: Thanks but this solution does not find the beginning of the sequence. A full byte can start from exxx3xxx etc and also there can be multiple occurrences of the numbers in the sequence that do not necessarily represent the start of a correct sequence.